# can't import com.google.api.client.http.* Cannot resolve symbol 'api'

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I keep getting the error message "Cannot resolve symbol 'api'."
I'm working on an application that tracks user location using the Google Places API. I've been trying to get it to work, but my import statements have been giving me trouble. I've looked in different places, and the sources I have found all tell me different things, such as...

1. Putting "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'" in the build.gradle. This usually results in the project not being able to sync. I researched a little bit on this and it mentions how I have to change SDKs, but that doesn't look too promising.
2. Putting "useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'" in the build.gradle. This helped the first import statement work ("import org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException;"), but not the rest.

I have the following import statements in my code.

```
import org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpParser;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
```

This is what build.gradle looks like:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tech.pattullo.teamzero"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.2.0'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I'm not sure yet how many of these I actually need, but I don't know how to go about resolving that error message with the 'api' symbol. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Google places, you only need this. You do not need to compile every single Google Play service.

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.8.0
```

If you want location tracking, I think you need the location API , not Places

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0
```

I don't know why you need Apache HTTP, but that seems unrelated to the current error

Comment: Okay. I forgot to mention that we're targeting Lollipop. Will we have to target Nougat to use play-services-places:9.8.0?

Comment: Not that I know of. Feel free to use the version you need.

Comment: So I did that and it worked for: import "com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;"
& "import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;" but not the rest

Comment: Right... Those are part of the core Google play services api dependencies needed to connect to any of the APIs.